# Python: How to zip a file on the fly while uploading it to SFTP?

Tags: python, stream, zip, on-the-fly

How to upload a file to SFTP server while zipping it on the fly.

Or in other words, how to take a local file, zip it and upload it to SFTP server at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution using [GzipFile](https://docs.python.org/2/library/gzip.html) writer and provide it fileObject that I use as a spy to get the data without actually writing to a file.
Then I yield the results from it right into a queue, that I build on other thread.

Long story short here is the code

### Usage

```
sftp.putfo(ReaderMaker(unzipped_file_path), remote_path)
```

### Implementation

```
COMPRESS_LEVEL = 9
BUFF_SIZE = 1024 * 1024

class ReaderMaker:
    def __init__(self, inputFile):
        self.it = self.compressor(inputFile)
        self.queue = Queue.Queue(10)
        task = Thread(target=self.zipper)
        task.start()

    def zipper(self):
        while True:
            try:
                data = self.it.next()
                while len(data) == 0:
                    data = self.it.next()
                self.queue.put(data)
            except StopIteration:
                break
        self.queue.put('')  # this will notify the last item read

    def read(self, n):
        return self.queue.get()

    def compressor(self, inputFile):
        class Spy:
            def __init__(self):
                self.data = ''

            def write(self, d):
                self.data = self.data + d

            def flush(self):
                d = self.data
                self.data = ''
                return d

        f_in = open(inputFile, 'rb')
        spy = Spy()

        f_out = GzipFile('dummy.gz', 'wrb+', COMPRESS_LEVEL, spy)

        while True:
            data = f_in.read(BUFF_SIZE)
            if len(data) == 0:
                break
            f_out.write(data)
            yield spy.flush()

        f_out.close()
        f_in.close()
        yield spy.flush()
```